# Trace IP from MAC

Tags: networking, server, firewall

I have a Virtual Server running Ubuntu at a hosting provider.

In the last couble of month I have experienced a dramatic increase of inbound traffic. All of it being UDP packets.

Looking in the logs i have litterary tens of thousands of lines on the form:

```
[UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=CULPRIT_MAC_ADDR? SRC=A_LOT_OF_IP_ADDR DST=MY_SERVER_IP
```

Before the spam started I was using at most 10 GB of traffic per month, now it has increased to 200 GB per month with 99.99% of it being inbound traffic only.

I can see UFW logs MAC address on the form:

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

And I know that eth0 mac address is the same as the first 12 hex numbers in above address.

Is there any way to do a ip lookup based on the full mac address from UFW log?

I would surely like to silence whatever that is spamming my server! Even though im not even near my traffic cap. :-)

Comment: The "SRC=A_LOT_OF_IP_ADDR" are the IP you are wanting. IP addresses, mac as well, can change and be spoofed, so the information does not do much for you and certainly does not identify any specific individual(s) responsible for your woes. The traffic is being blocked by your firewall. The only course of action you might have is to complain to the ip provider(s) of the source IP. Often they will not do much.

Comment: Yes I was fearing that part. Earlier when I shifting through data I saw a LOT of UDP packages was being sent to basically all broadcast addresses on my providers network.

The command iftop was flooded with traffic for the broadcast address and destination port 137, 138 and 17500. My ISP cleared those, the rest is a bit more tricky since all ip adresses comes from all over the world.

Comment: @bodhi: Could just add a "meta" answer, so I can close this one off as aswered?

Comment: would you like me to convert my comment to an answer?

Comment: Yes please. Anyhow I don't have a traffic issue anymore. Don't know if it was host provider who nailed it, or people suddenly lost interest in spamming my server. Anyway I am happy! :-)

Comment: Yes, they usually go away, it takes a lot of their resources as well.

Comment: Well moderate resources at my end. 700 kbps is easy to handle for server. I just don't want to hit traffic cap - since it affects my bank statement!  ;-)

Comment: I understand =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "SRC=A_LOT_OF_IP_ADDR" are the IP you are wanting. IP addresses, mac as well, can change and be spoofed, so the information does not do much for you and certainly does not identify any specific individual(s) responsible for your woes. The traffic is being blocked by your firewall. The only course of action you might have is to complain to the ip provider(s) of the source IP. Often they will not do much.